# htaccess, можно ли перенаправить на соседнюю директорию?

Tags: .htaccess

Настроено правило на перенаправление на php файл

```
RewriteRule ^razdel-lala/$ razdel.php?t1=$1
```

Можно ли настроить так, чтобы файл брался из соседней директории (не вложенной),
как бы так:

```
RewriteRule ^razdel-lala/$ ../dir1/razdel.php?t1=$1
```

Comment: Т.е. вы хотите чтобы реврайт работал вне корня сайта? Правильно я понимаю что каталог dir1 находится на одном уровне с корневым каталогом сайта? Если так, то это невозможно.

Comment: да верно, на одном уровне с сайтом. А если файл htaccess поместить на тот же уровень что и каталоги, возможно настроить такое?

Comment: положите в корень маленький php и вызывайте из него, откуда хотите

Comment: Тогда это не будет работать. Апач не будет иметь доступа к этому файлу. А чем обусловленно такое желание?

Comment: хотим поднять еще один сайт и использовать тот же php движок, движок вынести отдельно и использовать разными сайтами

Comment: @ДмитрийПортнов но ведь по сути у сайтов просто различаются базы данных тогда и все. Можно привязать сайт к той же самой папке, а просто в index менять БД в зависимости от запроса

Comment: ln для файлов и каталогов движка, а конфиги и пользовательское файловое хранилище индивидуально.